Cannot startup ActiveMQ Classic specifying a broker configuration file
I'm following ActiveMQ in Action published by Manning. I've successfully built the source-code "amq-in-action-example-src" using Maven in my Windows VM. I'm using the same version as the ActiveMQ in this book (i.e. 5.4.1). I'm following Chapter 4 to startup the broker, as below:
C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1>.\bin\activemq xbean:file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_311 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\jre
  Heap sizes: current=125952k  free=120624k  max=466432k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xmx512M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.classpath=C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\../conf;C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\../conf; -Dactivemq.home=C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\jliu2\apache-activemq-5.4.1\bin\..
Loading message broker from: xbean:file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from URL [file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 117; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'broker'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from URL [file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 117; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'broker'.
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:143)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:251)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 12 in XML document from URL [file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 117; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'broker'.

It seems like it is unable to recognize the broker in the XML file.
I'm pasting part of brokerA.xml here, which is the same content as in source-code of this book:
  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="BrokerA" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data">
  
    <!-- The transport connectors ActiveMQ will listen to -->
    <transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </transportConnectors>
    
    <networkConnectors>
        <networkConnector uri="static:(tcp://localhost:61617)" />
    </networkConnectors>

  </broker>
  
</beans>

Could you please advise what the error is and how to fix it?
I totally followed the command in the book as below:
.\bin\activemq xbean:src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml

(In Windows, run activemq not activemq console)
But it seemed unable to find the file. So I ran:
.\bin\activemq xbean:file:c:/jliu2/AMQinA-src/amq-in-action-example-src/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/book/ch4/brokerA.xml

which should be correct.
I also tried changing something in the brokeA.xml like xsi:schemaLocation, xmlns:amq, but that didn't work.
Please notice activemq can start successfully, and I've already successfully run some examples in chapter2 and 3. I am facing such issue in chapter4 specifying brokerA.xml.

Any feedback here?

I found the full brokerA.xml on GitHub. I tried running ActiveMQ Classic 5.4.1, but it is so old (over 13 years old) I didn't have the version of Java it required so I used 5.18.5 instead. The broker started fine using the following command:
./activemq xbean:/path/to/brokerA.xml

It's not clear what you're doing wrong, but I suspect the problem exists in the bit of brokerA.xml that you didn't paste into your question (e.g. the schema location(s)).
Generally speaking, I strongly recommend you use modern resources to learn ActiveMQ. Just a few years after ActiveMQ in Action was published ActiveMQ Artemis was introduced. This is the next generation broker from ActiveMQ. It provides better performance, higher scalability, more protocol support, additional features, & comprehensive documentation and examples.

I'm sorry for late reply. There is some time not logging here. Your suggestion is correct. By using AMQ5.18.5 and the source code on Github in your comments, there was not such error.
